# Unable to pause the current sound and play next

Tags: javascript, audio

I have a card matching game that I created here:

http://ewands.no-ip.biz/intern/guangjian/card/

The problem that I have is that I am unable to pause or mute the currently playing sound effect when a card is flipped, so if I immediately click the second card, no sound is heard. Using either pause and muted does not work. Any ideas?

```
//flipping_sound.pause(); does not work

//flipping_sound.muted; does not work

flipping_sound.play();
```

Comment: Do you use native audio api or is it some library?

Answer (score 1):

i'am using jquery and it's help for me:

```
flipping_sound.get(0).pause();
flipping_sound.get(0).currentTime = 0;
flipping_sound.get(0).play();
```

Comment: I copied this but there is a problem. And then I removed the get(0) and it works! Thanks!

Comment: @Jian Short sorry forgot about it - i have more than one player and  were some collision, so i add get(0) (think it's usefull only for me)

Comment: @Jian Short this does not apply to the question, but i think for images in you game its better to use one big sprite and operate with background position. sprite download once, and you be sure that all is fine,but than you use separeted images, people with bad connection can see no-image, or not fully downloaded img.

Answer (score 1):

first you need to check if is playing with this:

```
function isPlaying(audioElement) { return audioElement.paused; }
```

and if the audio is playing you need change the position of the audio with this

```
function changeAudioPosition(audioElement) { audioElement.currentTime = 0; }
```

and if the audio is not playing just play again

Comment: Thanks! But since I used Jquery I used the method below which is simpler.